# MSTest Web Report - How to set the the Output log info area in Test Report file Enlarged so that I can view the whole log for a test

Tags: tfs, report, azure-devops, mstest

I am running a MSTest suite and the report gets generated (both in .trx and web report )

In the web report, with respect to the log for test failures, Can we have the rectangle box enlarged. Is there a setting which I can modify to get the grayed rectangle area enalrged so that I can see the whole Log.

I am not sure whether I am stating it clearly. Hence attaching a screenshot. Thanks for the help in advance

[image].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the size of the detailed failed result area as following:
[image]

And you can also click on the test method link ("TestMethod1" in my screenshot) to open a detailed information page for that step.

Update：
Your logs has exceeded the 512 characters limitation of error message, that's why you cannot see it completely. A similar user voice for this can be found here: [Allow Error Messages Displayed in Microsoft Test Manager to exceed 512 characters](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/3449869-allow-error-messages-displayed-in-microsoft-test-m).

Comment: Thanks for that. I did what you said. But though the grey rectangle resizes, the content does not change. It remains truncated. In my screenshot attachment, it ends with contains(@ and still this does not change after resize. 

is there a way we can display the full error log here. 

Also, clicking on the link you mentioned, shows the same content

Comment: Thanks again Eddie. I believe this is to do with some config. Any thoughts about it.

Comment: @TimothyRajan Can you see the entire logs in the trx file?

Comment: @Eddir - Yes.  I am able to see the entire log in the trx file.